# Apache Tomcat admin page not displaying

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, admin, serve

I have installed apache tomcat in my PC in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation.

I have configured the server in eclipse by server->new server and selected the installed location.

After started the server in eclipse when i visit localhost:8085 the page displays as requested resource not available.

Then shutdown the server and again started the server via **monitor tomcat desktop app**,now i can view the admin page when i visit localhost:8085.

so why this happens and what is the difference between the both?

Comment: Eclipse write own configuration in tomcat.Check the tomcat configuration in eclipse folder(/Servers/Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost-config);

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse write own configuration in tomcat.Check the tomcat configuration in eclipse folder(/Servers/Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost-config);check eclipse wtpwebapps root folder is empty in eclipse so that error is occurred but tomcat installed folder  home page files are available so that home is coming.